# Python - How to call a function for each value in a csv

Tags: python, csv

```
with open('ids.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
myfile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in myfile:
    sel = row
    str(sel)
    print(sel)
    searcher(sel)
```

output looks like =

```
['311766349974,261240911883,201661478885']
```

So the csv is read as a list when I read row by row. I want to be able to take each value in the csv and call searcher with it as an argument but I don't know how to read value by value and then append it to a string (to add it to a url).
I had an excel file with rows of ids and so can I simply traverse cell by cell? Like using foreach value or something? If this can't work I could maybe have the function read a list instead do a string but there's thousands of values and I'm still testing how I want to run it. thanks for any help

Comment: ```for row in myfile:``` ```for item in row:```? I haven't tested this but could be what you want

Comment: Read something about lists and indexing in python.

Comment: It would seem that your file is comma-delimited, why are you using `delimiter=' '`? That means that each sublist (representing a single row) is coming as a single string, rather and something like `['311766349974', '261240911883', '201661478885']`. Is this what you actually want?

Comment: @roganjosh when I remove the delimiter my output is something like ['311766349974', '261240911883', '201661478885','','','','',''] for all the empty cells since each row has a different amount of cells filled. So this is closer to what I want since this is a list of strings instead of just one long one?

Comment: @Peaceful So I can't iterate value by value while reading and it would be better to read it all in as a list and then iterate through this? This might work better since I want to use run several instances so I can work on parts of the csv file at once since my tool is so slow.

Comment: Well now I don't know who is asking the question. Which format do you want? If you want to call a function on each individual string within a row, then this is probably easier than your current approach, then just filter/ignore the empty strings. Your overall goal is not clear to me.

Comment: @roganjosh I have a csv with a bunch of id's. I want to read this file and append each value to make it a string. Then I want to pass this string into a function. When I read the csv row by row I get a list and in the above code I am passing a list into the function 'search'. I think I might be best to save the list and then iterate through this list assign each value into my function.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for sel in row:
    searcher ( sel )
```